# Getting warnings and errors related to moment and ngx-moment during compilation (ng serve) along with broken-page for timeago pipe

Tags: angular, momentjs

> I am getting following compilation warning/errors along with broken
>   page related to timeago pipe
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 224:15-23
>   "export 'duration' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 558:12-18
>   "export 'isDate' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 64:52-60
>   "export 'isMoment' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 561:17-25
>   "export 'isMoment' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 573:15-23
>   "export 'isMoment' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 573:50-56
>   "export 'locale' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 409:15-24
>   "export 'parseZone' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 240:16-37
>   "export 'relativeTimeThreshold' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 267:15-19
>   "export 'unix' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 306:25-28
>   "export 'utc' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-moment/fesm2015/ngx-moment.js 306:47-50
>   "export 'utc' was not found in 'moment'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in
>   'blah\blah\node_modules\moment\src\lib\locale' i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with
>   warnings.
>
> Here is my angular stack @angular/cli                      7.0.7
>   @ngtools/webpack                  7.0.7 @schematics/angular
>   7.0.7 @schematics/update                0.10.7 rxjs                              6.3.3 typescript                        3.1.6 webpack                           4.19.1

I am using
"moment": "^2.19.3", 
"ngx-moment": "^3.5.0",
on nodejs 10.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package.json, update the versions of moment and ngx-moment as below:

“moment: “2.23.0”,
“ngx-moment”:”3.4.0”

Comment: Thanks. it was was issue with node10.20 with "moment": "^2.19.3", "ngx-moment": "^3.5.0". after replacing as you suggested its working now. (y)